# Panda time series showing end of business month considering holidays - ValueError: The truth value of a DatetimeIndex is ambiguous

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a timeseries using pandas to allow me to filter a dataframe I have to include only the data corresponding to the first and last business day of each month. I, however, have to take account of bank holidays. In a first step I am trying to create a timeseries that contains all end of business month dates, considering holidays. My start of my code looks as follows (filtering isn't included yet):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as calendar

stocks = pd.read_csv('appl_1980_2014.csv')
stocks['Date']=pd.to_datetime(stocks['Date'])
stocks=stocks.set_index('Date',verify_integrity=True)

cal = calendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start=stocks.tail(1).index[0], end=stocks.head(1).index[0])
a=pd.bdate_range(end=stocks.head(1).index[0], start=stocks.tail(1).index[0], freq='BM',holidays=holidays)
```

When I run the code I, however, get an error message stating:

```
 File "C:/Users/43153/Documents/General/ACE/pre-test/apple_stocks.py", line 17, in <module>
    a=pd.bdate_range(end=stocks.head(1).index[0], start=stocks.tail(1).index[0], freq='BM',holidays=holidays,weekmask=None)

  File "C:\ML\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 1678, in bdate_range
    elif holidays or weekmask:

  File "C:\ML\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2394, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__

ValueError: The truth value of a DatetimeIndex is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is causing this behaviour? I have not been able to find an answer online yet unfortunately.

(If anybody has a more elegant suggestion to also include the start of the business months in the timeseries I would be very interested to make the filtering more straightforward later.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```sh
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as calendar
>>> from pandas.tseries.offsets import CDay
>>> stocks = pd.read_csv('appl_1980_2014.csv')
>>> stocks['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stocks['Date'])
>>> stocks = stocks.set_index('Date', verify_integrity=True)
>>> cal = calendar()
>>> week_days = pd.bdate_range(stocks.tail(1).index[0].date(), stocks.head(1).index[0].date(), freq=CDay(calendar=cal))
>>> first_days = pd.date_range(min(week_days), max(week_days), freq='BMS')
>>> last_days = pd.date_range(min(week_days), max(week_days), freq='BM')
>>> first_days.append(last_days)
DatetimeIndex(['1981-01-01', '1981-02-02', '1981-03-02', '1981-04-01',
               '1981-05-01', '1981-06-01', '1981-07-01', '1981-08-03',
               '1981-09-01', '1981-10-01',
               ...
               '2013-09-30', '2013-10-31', '2013-11-29', '2013-12-31',
               '2014-01-31', '2014-02-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-30',
               '2014-05-30', '2014-06-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=806, freq=None)
```

Comment: True, but what I need to ultimately have is the last business day of each month, just removing the holidays doesn't allow me to do that, I think.

Comment: It throws an error. I am not sure how this is doing the intended yet though? (but perhaps I ma misunderstanding the code) I need to have a list which contains the last working day of each month (and ideally the first working day of each month, though I can do that separately).

Comment: I edited my answer again. And as you said, I did it separately. I tried at the bash and did not get the error.